# How do memory integrity checks work?

Tags: disassembly, debugging, anti-debugging

How does a memory integrity check work? For example, the `.code` memory region is scanned by this check and then changes can be detected and the program will return with an event that will exit the application. If anyone has a source of how something like this would work it'd be much appreciated to study off of.

Answer (score 2):

There is no point writing you example code you may as well read this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17636/Dynamic-TEXT-Section-Image-Verification

I guess you're wanting to write an anti-cheat?